# What is the geometrical interpretation of these three integrals?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

What is the geometrical interpretation of these three integrals?

1) $$\int_C~ (x+y) ~dx + (x^2y)~ dy$$

2) $$\int_C~ \vec{F}\cdot d \vec{r}$$

3) $$\int_C~ xyz~ ds$$
I know they are all line integrals and I know how to compute them but I'm not sure as to what they mean physically.

Comment: Please give some context for the question.  If $\vec F$ is force, then the line integral in $(2)$ is the work done in moving an object with mass $m$ along the path $C$.

Comment: Okay I understand that one now. Could you elaborate on 1) and 3) please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$
\int_{a}^{b}f(x)\,dx
$$

Let's look at the definite integral of a function $f(x)$ over a range $[a,\,b]$. The geometric interpretation here is that we are slicing the area under the curve $f(x)$ bounded by the x-axis into smaller and smaller vertical columns and summing them up.

$$
\oint_C \vec{F} \,d\vec{r}
$$

Consider the integral above. Assuming we are operating in the xy-plane, the geometric interpretation is that we are integrating a closed curve $\vec{r}(t)$ over a vector field $\vec{F}(x,y)$. Similar to the case of $f(x)$ above, we are summing up an near infinite number of something. In the case of line integrals over vector fields, we are summing up a near infinite number of dot-products.

A good example is forces acting on an object. From physics, the work $W$ done by a force $\vec{F}$ on an object over a distance $\Delta\vec{r}$ is equal to
$$W=\vec{F}\cdot \Delta\vec{r}$$

Go back to the line integral above. Now, intepret $\vec{F}$ as a vector field whose vectors represent forces at every point in the domain of $\vec{F}$.

Some object is moving along the curve C with respect to time.
Let us parameterize this curve C as a function of, let's say, time.
$$C\rightarrow\vec{r}(t)\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,a\leqslant\,t\leqslant\,b$$
If the curve is closed, then $\vec{r}(a)=\vec{r}(b)$

Now the velocity vector of this object will always be tangent to the curve C, and we can interpret this as the change in position $\Delta \vec{r}$. If $\vec{F}(x,y)$ has partial derivatives which are continuous on the domain containing the closed curve C, then we can sum up the dot products of the force vectors and the tangent vectors. What we will end up with is the amount of work done on the object by the force $\vec{F}$.

Fun point: If $\vec{F}$ is conservative, the integral will always equal 0. (Think of gravity.)

Back to your question: All of the integrals you posted denote the same thing, the difference being the notation. Number two is the most descriptive, while number 1 is the one which has caused me the most headaches trying to understand this.

For me, the important thing when learning these integrals is to think of $dr$, $ds$ and $dx, dy$ as infinitsimals of respectively; the tangent vector, the unit tangent vector, and the components of the tangent vector. They relate to the same thing, and I suggest getting to know them intimately so as to avoid confusion when doing line integrals. They should all reduce to a single integral of one variable, although most of these quickly escalate in complexity. The fun point about the integrals you posted is that they all are part of Green's Theorem which makes solving the integrals a lot easier.

Comment: Nice answer! The only part I don't get is why the line integrals would have to be zero if the field is conservative.

Comment: Since you're asking about line integrals, I will assume you're familiar with the curl of a vector field. (If not, get familiar with it before continuing on to Green's Theorem.) As it happens, the curl of a conservative vector field is always zero, and Green's theorem states that the line integral over a closed curve on a vector field is EXACTLY the same as taking the double integral of the curl of the field over the area bounded by the curve - and if the curl is zero, you're left with summing an infinite number of zeros.